# Firebase - Do I need security rules with App Check?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebase-app-check

I have implemented an App with a corresponding App Check on Firebase. My app does not authenticate users - any user should be able to come and read/write from the database, but only *within* the app.

For ease of explaining, suppose my app is just a button, and each time any [unauthenticated] user presses the button, it increments the counter stored in the database by 1. This requires any user to have "write" access. What I want to *avoid*, is a user taking my public firebase config, and doing something like increment(100).

Is App Check sufficient to stop this? Because surely that would nullify any requests made outside my app? Otherwise, what security rules would be needed to make this secure.

Comment: "*Is App Check sufficient to stop this?*" - No.  See the duplicates for a more complete discussion.